# KillMeNowExcel in Title of Excel Workbook

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Occasionally, one user's Excel spreadsheet will have '- KillMeNowExcel' instead of the standard '- Excel' in the title.  This is on an HP Laptop running Windows 7 64-bit with Office 2013.  Any idea why this is happening?

The user is running Microsoft Security Essentials for antivirus/antimalware. I searched the registry for KillMeNow and it returned 0 results. The only program they have installed themselves I know of is Snagit by Techsmith, Spotify and iTunes.  There are a few other programs which they have installed, but they are work related industry specific programs.

I checked the Excel binary with ResourceHacker, and it was not in the binary.

[image: KillMeNowExcel]

Comment: It might be third-party software modifying the window title. Does the device have antivirus/antimalware running? Do  the users install random stuff from the internet? It might be someone's harmless joke or it might be a sign that if this kinda stuff got installed, much worse could also be installed.

Comment: I am running Excel Office 365 and I can control the value you mention with this key:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Registration\{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}]
"ExcelName"="Excel11"`

As you are on Office 2013, if you open Regedit and search under:
`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\(versionnumber)\Registration\` maybe also check `HKCU`
For KIllMeNowExcel, do you see it?

Comment: Could you post the screen shot !!

Comment: Perhaps, the executable resources were modified.  Download a program called `Reshack` and find the title value there.  It may be changed or it may not be changed.  http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: Uninstall Office completely with easy fix tool and then reinstall Office, maybe any add-ins or softwares change it.